# control brightness on the second monitor

Tags: brightness

I use HP ProBook 440 with a second monitor [HP Z24i]
Currently I can control only the brightness of the laptop monitor with 'Brightness Controller'. I tried f.lux and DisplayCAL. The first doesn't work, the second one has many options and looks extremely complicated. I am novice user in Ubuntu and I would like to have any simple (GUI) solution to make the second screen at least not so bright.
best 
Alex

Answer (score 1):

the Brightness Controller should be able to manage brightness of the second monitor:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/adjust-external-monitor-brightness-ubuntu

If it's not the case anymore, as a temporary solution you can have your first approach with command line interface, if you execute the following command you can get the list of displays:

```
xrandr -q | grep " connected"
LVDS connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
DisplayPort-0 connected 1920x1200+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
```

my second screen is commected via **DisplayPort-0**, I copy and use that information to perform the next command and fix bightness:

```
xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --brightness 0.7
```

Comment: Hi lese, Brightness Controller works! Thank you so much!